# Understanding streaming in python-requests and in general

Tags: python, django, streaming, python-requests, chunked

I'm really having troubles wrapping my head around this and maybe someone can point me in the right direction:

I'm using python (django framework) for an web-application and i have an additional web socket server that receives chunked binary data from the browser. I want to send (or stream) those chunks to another server using the python-requests library.

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) you have to provide a generator as the data attribute:

```
arr = []

def streamer():
    global arr
    for i in arr:
        yield i

#lets say this function will get called when a "stream-start" message is sent to the web-socket server
def onStart():
    resp = requests.post("http://some.url/chunked", data=streamer())

#lets say this function will get called when a chunk of binary data is sent to the web-socket server
def onChunk(chunk):
    arr.append(chunk)
```

In this scenario, how would I possible be able to send anything since `arr` is empty when I send the request. How can I keep the connection open, so that every chunk will be sent?

I think there is some major issue that I don't understand about streaming in general. So, next to hints about solving my actual problem I would also appreciate any recommendation of tutorials or a good read on this subject.

Comment: Presumably the idea is not to call `requests.post` until you've finished receiving all the chunks.

Comment: I'll try and write a proper answer, but what you are looking for is a form of concurrency, where your `streamer()` generator blocks until data is available. Starting point: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf

Comment: @Aya That wouldn't work in my case because I need the live response from the server. To be a little bit more specific: I'm sending chunks of live audio data and want to receive transcripted text that should be visible while the person is still speaking.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, that sounds like the right idea. Thanks for the link...I'm having a look at it.

Comment: @basilikum TBH, I don't see how you can do this with HTTP. If the idea is to have a loop where you send a chunk of audio data, and get back some text, it would seem to violate the HTTP protocol. In theory, the server isn't supposed to send a response until the client has finished sending its request, so you'd either have to send all the chunks before receiving a response, or make multiple requests.